# Out of bounds error on a simple String array

Tags: java, runtime-error

I am trying to make a method that will divide a String up into groups of 4, and I keep getting an out of bounds error. I can't understand where it is coming from, is there an easier way to do this, or what is causing the error?

EDIT: SOLVED bad brackets means int MAX isn't assinged the correct value

The relevant code

```
public void ColumnCode(String plaintext) {
    System.out.println("Please enter the number of columns you want");
    int columns = slave.getNum();

    int MAX = (plaintext.length()-1/columns)+1; //number of times to iterate the for loop
    String[] groups = new String[MAX];

    for(int i = 0; i < MAX; i++) {
        if((4*i)+4 > plaintext.length()) groups[i] = plaintext.substring(4*i);
        else groups[i] = plaintext.substring(4*i, 4*(i+1));
        System.out.println(groups[i]);
    }
}
```

Example error message:

```
Now please enter the plaintext to be encrypted: 
THIS IS A MESSAGE
Please enter the number of columns you want
4
THIS
 IS 
A ME
SSAG
E
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: -3
    at java.lang.String.substring(Unknown Source)
    at Cryptopher.ColumnCodeClass.ColumnCode(ColumnCodeClass.java:26)
    at Cryptopher.mainFile.encrypt(mainFile.java:86)
    at Cryptopher.mainFile.runTheProgram(mainFile.java:55)
    at Cryptopher.mainFile.main(mainFile.java:36)
```

Comment: You are getting the index of of bounds error because on the last iteration you are suppose to have 4 elements in your array, but your array is only populated with 1 element ("E").

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is caused by this line:
`int MAX = (plaintext.length()-1/columns)+1;`

Order of operations will do the subtraction inside the brackets *after* 1/columns is evaluated.

This causes the inner difference to become (in the case of 4 columns) `plaintext.length()` - 0.25, in effect making your MAX larger than the array size, causing your error.

Comment: Ah, that makes sense. On the aside, would it not be 'plaintext.length()-0' since its assigned to an int?

Answer (score 1):

You have a bracket in the wrong place.

It should be `int MAX = (plaintext.length()-1)/columns+1`